# Getting data (Image) from Json

Tags: android, json

I'm making a blog reader for Android and problem is I'm a new in programming. Trying to get data from Json. I did it for String data("title","author"), but I don't know how to do it for images ("thumbnail"). My question is: how to add "thumbnail" at the left part of the listView in front of "title" and "author".

```
  {
      "id": 109,
      "url": "http://integrallab.ru/index.php/categorii-so-statyami/2013-10-25-13-26-29/3-ideas",
      "title": "Article title",
      "date": "2015-03-17 09:21:43",
      "author": "Nikolai Boiko",
      "thumbnail": "http://integrallab.esy.es/pic/3_things.jpg"
    },
```

the code is:

......

```
  private final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
```

.....

```
private void handleBlogResponse() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (mBlogData == null) {
            updateDisplayForError();

    } else {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blogPosts =
                    new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i=0; i<jsonPosts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                String author = post.getString(KEY_AUTHOR);
                author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();

                HashMap<String, String> blogPost = new HashMap<String, String>();
                blogPost.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                blogPost.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);

                blogPosts.add(blogPost);
            }

          String[] keys = { KEY_TITLE, KEY_AUTHOR };
            int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, blogPosts,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys,ids);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            logException(e);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are getting the url of a image. Just take a imageView. For example:

```
ImageView logo = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
```

and this chunks of code may work:

```
       try {
                // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(" http://corporate2.bdjobs.com/21329.jpg").getContent());
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(m.getLogo()).getContent());
                //  http://corporate2.bdjobs.com/21329.jpg
                logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                //convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cardlayout);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but for now it's too challenge for me. I'm just considering to add a few pictures in few posts. Add a third variable in my code.  Something like this private final String KEY_THUMBNAIL = "thumbnail";
But I don't know how to reflect it here. For another two I use this array:
String[] keys = { KEY_TITLE, KEY_AUTHOR };
            int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, blogPosts,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys,ids);

Comment: In that case you don't have to do that much stuffs. I am updating my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks again for your previous post and link)) with 'volley library'! I spent some time trying to understand how it's work and I did my project using this lib. I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason for doing this yourself,  check out [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.